# Log entries api not retrieving log entries

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

I am trying to retrieve custom logs for a particular project in google-cloud. I am using this api:

```
https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/entries:list
```

as per the example given in [this link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/list).

The below is the payload:

```
{
  "filter": "projects/projectA/logs/slow_log",
 
  "resourceNames": [
    "projects/projectA"
  ]
}
```

There is a custom log based metric called **slow_log** I created in that projectA, which gathers query logs from cloud-SQL database in that project. I also generated data before calling this api. I am able to see the data in stack-driver console, but unable to get it from the rest call.

Every time I run this api, I only get this response and nothing else:

```
  "nextPageToken": "EAA4suKu3qnLwbtrSg8iDSIDCgEAKgYIgL7q8wVSBwibvMSMvhhglPDiiJzdjt_zAWocCgwI2buKhAYQlvTd2gESCAgLEMPV7ukCGAAgAQ"
```

1. Is there anything missing here?
2. How is it possible to pass time range in this query?

### Update

Changed the request as per the comment below as gave the full path of the logs: still only the token is displayed

```
{
  "filter": "projects/projectA/logs/cloudsql.googleapis.com%2Fmysql-slow.log",
  "projectIds": [
    "projectA"
  ],
  "orderBy": "timestamp desc"
}
```

Also I give this command from command line:

```
gcloud logging read logName="projects/projectA/logs/cloudsql.googleapis.com%2Fmysql-slow.log"
```

then it fetches the logs in command line, so I am not sure what I am missing in the api explorer and postman where I get only nextpage token.

Comment: Try adding ```"orderBy": "timestamp desc"``` parameter.

Comment: Thank you added this "orderBy": "timestamp desc" but still only the token is displayed

Comment: Use this API - https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/logs/list  to check exact path to your log and copy it into ```"filter"``` field.

Comment: Are you requesting the logs from the ProjectA or from another project?

Comment: @Sergiusz updated the code and gave the full path of the logs , but still getting only the token after new log generation

Answer (score 3):

`resourceNames`, `filter` and `orderBy` are mandatory, try like this:

```
{
  "resourceNames": [
    "projects/projectA"
  ],
  "filter": "projects/projectA/logs/cloudsql.googleapis.com%2Fmysql-slow.log",
  "orderBy": "timestamp desc"
}
```

Comment: https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/entries:list?resourceNames=projects/projectA&filter="logName=projects/projectA/logs/cloudsql.googleapis.com/mysql-slow.log"&orderBy=timestamp desc.         //This is still giving only the token

Comment: Check your [API quotas](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas), maybe you are receiving empty response because you are over limit.

Comment: Note that "resourceNames", "filter" and "orderBy" parameters are all required to have a meaningful response.